# How to adapt my exploit strategy when "00" is part of the targeted return address and the victim uses strcpy

Tags: linux, exploit, c

I intend to exploit the following program on an x86 Linux machine with NX enabled (ASLR and stack canary disabled). The goal is to get a shell.

```
//vuln.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
 char buf[256]; /* [1] */ 
 strcpy(buf,argv[1]); /* [2] */
 printf("%s\n",buf); /* [3] */
 fflush(stdout);  /* [4] */
 return 0;
}
```

My strategy is to use ret2libc and inject my payload:

```
payload = <filler> + <addr of system> + <addr of exit> + <arg1 for system>
```

The payload intends to use system API to call /bin/sh to get a shell. However, addr of system contains 00 in the middle and strcpy will drop my payload after null terminator.

What would be the strategy to exploit this binary then?

Comment: What about one of the other exec* functions? Or just use ret2libc's big brother ROP?

Comment: @wireghoul, can you elaborate on the exec* ones?

Comment: You can return into any function in libc, system isn't the only one that can execute commands. http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Executing-a-File.html